# Attribute error when web scraping GitHub user stars

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am getting error while scraping GitHub stars of the user can any one help me fix this.
I am using python.
my code

```py
def total_stars(username):
    html = requests.get('https://github.com/'+username ).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    total_commit = soup.select_one('text-bold  color-fg-default + span').text
    print(total_commit)
```

error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got the answer @lex, the way you want to travel through the html to get the element needs to be put into your `select_one()` or `select()` calls.

Like below,

```
>>> soup.select_one('#js-pjax-container > div.container-xl.px-3.px-md-4.px-lg-5 > div > div.flex-shrink-0.col-12.col-md-3.mb-4.mb-md-0 > div > div.js-profile-editable-replace > div.d-flex.flex-column > div.js-profile-editable-area.d-flex.flex-column.d-md-block > div.flex-order-1.flex-md-order-none.mt-2.mt-md-0 > div > a:nth-child(3) > span').text
```

**or**

```
>>> soup.select_one('#js-pjax-container div.container-xl.px-3.px-md-4.px-lg-5 div div.flex-shrink-0.col-12.col-md-3.mb-4.mb-md-0 div div.js-profile-editable-replace div.d-flex.flex-column div.js-profile-editable-area.d-flex.flex-column.d-md-block div.flex-order-1.flex-md-order-none.mt-2.mt-md-0 div a:nth-child(3) span').text
```

**or**

```
>>> soup.select('#js-pjax-container > div.container-xl.px-3.px-md-4.px-lg-5 > div > div.flex-shrink-0.col-12.col-md-3.mb-4.mb-md-0 > div > div.js-profile-editable-replace > div.d-flex.flex-column > div.js-profile-editable-area.d-flex.flex-column.d-md-block > div.flex-order-1.flex-md-order-none.mt-2.mt-md-0 > div > a:nth-child(3) > span')[0].text
```

**Output**:

```
'16'
```

Note: This is based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69619674/i-m-getting-attribute-error-in-web-scraping/69619971#comment123056713_69619756).

Answer (score 0):

Use a less *delicate* path, not one that's prone to even small site/html changes. The longer chains of identifiers will break quite easily.

The "stars" number is in a link to a tab of the user's profile (starred repos), like `https://github.com/aneroid?tab=stars`. And you already have the username & url.

So simplify the selector to something more robust:
`a[href="https://github.com/aneroid?tab=stars"] > span`

The code would become:

```py
def total_stars(username):
    url = 'https://github.com/' + username
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    # it's not `total_commit`, that's in your other function ;-)
    stars = soup.select_one(f'a[href="{url}?tab=stars"] > span').text
    print(stars)
    # return int(stars)
```

Btw, the *`followers`* and *`following`* links have a similar structure, so `?tab=followers` and `?tab=following` if you want those as well.